# How to include Android module library (with SO libs) into another Android module library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with next structure:

```
project
|--app
|----build.gradle
|--libA
|----src/main/jniLibs/<arch>/libA.so
|----build.gradle
|--libB
|----src/main/cpp/*.cpp
|----CMakeLists.txt
|----build.gradle
|--build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
```

When **app's** build.gradle has both libs as module dependencies:

```
app  libA  libB
 ↓     ↑      ↑
 --------------
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    
    implementation project(path: ':libA')
    implementation project(path: ':libB')
    ...
}
```

then I see that built APK contains all SO libraries (libA.so and libB.so):

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
app -> libA -> libB
```

so that I can build just *libA* module and *libB* will also be built and included in **libA.aar** with its classes and *.so libs.

I'm trying to add libB as dependency to libA.

LibA's build.gradle now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(path: ':libB')
    ...
}
```

And I commented line:

```
// implementation project(path: ':libB')
```

in *app's* build.gradle.

But after build I don't see **libB.so** in resulting **libA.aar**. However libB module classes are there.

Env:

```
AndroidStudio: 4.2.1
AndroidGradlePlugin: 4.1.0
Gradle: 6.5
```

Comment: Did you fixed it?

Comment: @VíctorMartín, unfortunately no

Comment: Any luck so far @Sheikh?

Comment: @i_raqz, hi! I haven't done any tests with it since :(